# Filter for Reducing Background Noise in Image

Tags: image-processing, filters, computer-vision, lowpass-filter, smoothing

I have images where there is a lot of "black" background (few shades of black). (In many images at least half the pixels are background). I need to get interest points from the image, but because the background is not smooth (although black) , I get a lot of "false" key points in the background.
What filter/s will fit best to keep the details in the image but will smooth the background as much as possible ?
I tried median filter, but the size needed to reduce background noise ([5 5]) was to strong for the small details in the image I wanted to keep sharp, same for Gaussian with very small sigma.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some images here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small noises erosion followed by dilation can help as the erosion will clear the noise and dilation will bring back the deleted boundaries.Though i have still not implemented this Erosion+dilation option myself on grayscale but may be they can help

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce image size or use scale-invariant interest point detector which can deal with blurry images.

Please note that using some elaborate denoising algorithm may change each image in a slightly different way, thus possibly distorting the positions of your interest points.